# Why 0.toFixed(2) print "0" instead of "0.00"?

Tags: javascript

Why does `0.toFixed(2)` print `0` instead of `0.00`?

Comment: [It prints `0.00` for me](https://jsfiddle.net/e1o2hhgp/).

Comment: Can you share where you are running JS?

Comment: `0.toFixed(2) => SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal.`

Comment: `0.toFixed(2)` is a syntax error. You need two dots - `0..toFixed(2)`

Comment: @solanki... Can you please tell us, which interpreter you use?

Comment: @Mijago: I am working on reactjs.

Comment: Why people are down vote my question. I also not get any syntax in my console. It is a relevant question

Answer (score 4):

### The correct answer:

Use a variable (noted by Rajesh in the comments)!

```
var num = 0
var fixedStr = num.toFixed(2);
```

This just looks better, is easier to understand and also safer, as it will throw errors to you if any occur.

**Some Warning**

Please note that some interpreters (just like the chrome console) do throw an error if you do `0.toFixed(2)`, as it is no valid JS to them. If you use a variable or brackets around the `0`, it will be okay for them.

### Another way for doing it

Also noted in the comments (by 4castle):
You can also use the following:

```
0..toFixed(2)
```

As the first dot will be interpreted as a decimal point, this will be okay for the interpreter and be parsed into `"0.00"`.
But **please** do not use this, use a variable. It just looks horrible and not everyone understands what this should do (or why it magically works).

Comment: Sweeeetet and Shorrrt!!!!!. Thanks.

Comment: Note a minor difference. `0.toFixed` will throw error where as `(0).toFixed` will not

Comment: Another option is to use `0..toFixed(2)`. The first is interpreted as a decimal point, and the second is interpreted as a property accessor.

Comment: @4castle I'm more interested in knowing *how OP got **0** instead of error*

Answer (score 2):

If you store 0 in a var, or if you use (0), it give `0.00`.

```
(0).toFixed(2)
"0.00" 

var x = 0;
x.toFixed(2)
"0.00"
```